# How to determine scale factor of x-values in a grid that have been both moved and scaled?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm converting vector file types and during the conversion, the $x$-values are both moved and scaled.  In the image below, the left-hand blue point had an $x$-coordinate at $0$ while the right-hand blue coordinate $x$-value was at $100$ in the original file.  Note that I know the values of the blue points as they were in the original file, but I do not know the values of the other points as they were in the original file.  Using the two blue point $x$-values in the new file, how can I determine the $x$-values of all the points as they were in the original file?
As a starting point, I've tried $\frac{110.5-10.05}{100}$ to get the amount that the $x$-values had been scaled, but this is slightly off as it equals $1.0045$, and for this test example, I happen to know that I moved the $x$-values $10$ then scaled everything by $1.005$.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: what about $y$ values? Do they remain the same?

Comment: No, they do not remain the same...but if I can figure out the x-values, then I should be able to do the y-values.  I didn't want to discuss the y-values, because they are also inverse (sort-of) of the original file, which I figured would complicate the discussion

Comment: so $x_n=a\cdot x_o+b$, where $x_n$ - "new" $x$ and $x_o$ - "old" $x$?

Comment: @Vasya, yes, but note that the coordinates are moved THEN scaled.  So, I think that would be Xn = (Xo +b) * a... correct?

Comment: the order does not really matter, if you open parenthesis you get $a\cdot x_o + b\cdot a$ which is the same thing

Comment: Yes.  And actually, I'm not 100% certain whether it is scaled first them moved or the other way around, but I'm assuming it is moved then scaled, as that seems to be the case, but I will need to test it based on the formula which I am asking about.  Note that in my example it is moved then scaled, but I'm not certain about the actual files yet.

Comment: so if you have two pairs $(x_1, x_2)$ and $(x_3, x_4)$ where $x_1$ and $x_3$ are "old" $x$ you have $x_2=ax_1+b$, $x_4=ax_3+b$ and you can easily figure it out as $a=(x_2-x_4)/(x_1-x_3)$ and after you find $a$, $b=x_2-ax_1$.

Comment: With your math, I've actually gotten the values a = 1.0045 and b = 10.05.  b is easy because I know that x1 is Zero so b = x2.  And I showed I arrived at a = 1.0045 in my question.  But note, if I wish to work backward, as is what I need to do--if I divide x4 by a then subtract b (110.5/1.0045 -10.05) I get 99.9549... instead of 100.  I need to be able to get back to 100.

Comment: Vasya, also note that a should really be 1.005 and not 1.0045...in a way, that's really my question, how to get a = 1.005 with the information provided?

Comment: If you moved 10 then scaled 1.005, $x_4$ should be $110.55$, not $110.5$

Comment: I can't believe I did that!!!!  Thanks for finding that error.  Recalculating.

Comment: if $x_4$ is $110.55$, you are using the wrong $a$, it should be $1.005$

Comment: Yes...I'm full of errors today.  I realized that after posting and edited my comment.  Thanks for all your help

Comment: If you had exactly three points (as equilateral triangle as possible), then you could directly calculate the rotation, translation, and reflection needed:$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}x_i^\prime = \chi_x x_i + \gamma_x y_i + \tau_x \\ y_i^\prime = \chi_y y_i + \gamma_y y_i + \tau_y \end{aligned}\right.$$You need three points to determine $\chi_x$, $\gamma_x$, $\tau_x$, $\chi_y$, $\gamma_y$, and $\tau_y$.